# Can you have a collection that's randomly distributed in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that's essentially just a collection of unique IDs, and I want to store them randomly distributed so I can quickly just findOne instead of sampling them since it's quicker than aggregation.

I ran the following aggregation to sort it randomly:

```
db.my_coll.aggregate([{"$sample": {"size": 1200000}}, {"$out": {db: "db", coll: "my_coll"}}], {allowDiskUse: true})
```

it seems to work?

```
  db.my_coll.find():

  { _id: 581848, schema_version: 1 },
  { _id: 1184557, schema_version: 1 },
  { _id: 213688, schema_version: 1 },
  ....
```

Is this allowed? I thought _id is a default index, and it should always be sorted by the index. I'm only ever removing elements from this collection, so it's fine if they don't get inserted randomly, but I don't know if this is just a hack that might at some point behave differently.

Comment: Turns out I don't need to. I found a query that scales well: db.pages.aggregate([{$match: {"dateAdded": null}}, {$limit: 5000}, {$sample: {size: 1}}]). Using limit kept this query just as good for my purposes as keeping the collection stored randomly.

Comment: edit: this doesn't actually work well because the documents are all stored in order. Even if I do a limit: 1000 or something, it will choose 1000 from the bottom 1000 _ids